# Why is there a grid of mortality prediction surival models in deepHit?

Tags: machine-learning, survival

I am attaching an image below for algorithm 1 as given in the supplementary material of DeepHit paper. The link to 1 page supplementary material is here : http://medianetlab.ee.ucla.edu/papers/AAAI_2018_DeepHit_Appendix

[image: Algorithm 1 in DeepHit Supplementary Material]

I am unable to understand the reason why a mxk grid of ML predictors is being trained? (Here m = number of discrete time points and k is the number of risks). 
Is the idea to train a grid of models and then pick the best one among these? Or is it some kind of ensembling happening? If I understand correctly, the covariates are available only from t=0(or m=0). Then why is the author creating all these smaller datasets and training a model on each one of these?

I am sorry I am survival analysis noob. I just know the basic concepts. But don't know about why we would train an entire grid of models?